# .NET Core 3.1 + GraphQL + MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, graphql, .net-core-3.1

Is there any implementation example/best practice/documentation for document-based databases and GraphQL for .NET stack?

I am using MongoDB with .NET Core 3.1 and I would consider switching from REST to GraphQL, but I need additional info about it.

Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, this question is opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/graphql/

This will work basically irrespective of technology. You are adding the GraphQL layer on top of data residing in your database.